# How to deal with an unproductive colleague ( supposedly due to medication)?

Tags: germany, leadership, people-management, morale

I work in a medium-sized company in Germany, which is part of a fairly large corporation. In my department there are two teams in one office space. We all get along very well, but recently the mood is tilting a bit. A new colleague in the other team is not doing his job at the expense of the others, seems unmotivated and has been seen sleeping on the desk several times. Gradually, rumors began to circulate that he was the future son-in-law of the team leader and that he was taking medication and was therefore sleepy. At least the former has been confirmed in the meantime.

Both team leaders and the department head were made aware of the situation several times and seem to have been aware of it from the beginning. Nevertheless, they do not react to the situation.

No one in the department objects to giving someone with an impairment the opportunity to work here. However, resentment is growing as more and more work falls to the remaining colleagues in the affected team. At the same time, they feel unfairly treated, since their work and performance are equated both monetarily and in the appreciation of the managers.

In Germany, an illness does not have to be disclosed by the person concerned if its symptoms do not pose a risk to others. Thus, even the manager cannot communicate the illness of the colleague or the sleepiness due to medication if the colleague does not consent to this. This seems to me to be a dilemma, because I think that it would help the mood if there was an open approach to it. If the colleagues were told openly that the affected colleague can only work less than they can, this would certainly calm the mood, even if he earns the same, since he is not responsible for the illness and solidarity is a high value in Germany. But the supposed suppression of the situation is causing the mood to tilt more and more.

What can I do to defuse the situation apart from approaching the manager again? What suggestions can I make to the manager? Since our department is not particularly large, I would like to avoid addressing the colleague directly so as not to defame the colleagues who are complaining.

Comment: What is your stake in this argument?

Comment: Since we work in the same department, the poor performance of the colleague in the neighboring team affects me just as much, although not as directly as the colleagues from the same team.

Comment: Is he new to just your specific company, or new to the workforce in general?

Comment: I don't understand why is this affectin your performance though, who is telling you that your performance, or your teams is inadequate? Did the manager ask you to pick up the slack for the collegue, or are you just doing it to cover it?

Comment: He comes from another area that has relatively little to do with his current job and from another company. It is generally questionable what qualifies him for the job.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul His team works with a shared worklist. If one person doesn't keep up with his work, more falls to the others. Lately, a lot of his responsibilities have been shifted to the others, as he was not able to finish his share. My tasks are partly dependent on the results of their work, so I have to ask the collegues from the other team to hurry and then recieve snappy answers because tey are fed up with it. Also I cant continue with this part myself as long as the results are missing...

Comment: I would focus on how it affects *your* work and maybe mention, as an aside, that work that should be done by him seems to be done by other people and they seem overworked. All the other stuff about whether he is qualified for the job, the mood of the other team, the illness he has doesn't seem to concern you and is just noise. The important bit for you is that your tasks are getting delayed.

Comment: How does your pay system work? Is it possible that this person is sleeping on the job and charging time for it, which would be fraud? Framing it like that might raise more company eyebrows since time theft is usually taken pretty seriously. If you can get a sympathetic manager and help them prove that the person is charging time spent sleeping, that could work.

Comment: Unless you are his manager, THIS IS NOT YOUR RESPONSIBILITY. STAY OUT OF IT.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is quite a bit to unpack here.

> His team works with a shared worklist. If one person doesn't keep up with his work, more falls to the others

That's a horrible idea and you can now clearly see exactly why, as they just dump the work at teams responsibility, but do not give them any tools for effective management of it. Just go and do, or you as a team will be held responsible only works is when the manager/leader is part of said team and has power to discipline and reward.

Between

> My tasks are partly dependent on the results of their work, so I have to ask the collegues from the other team to hurry and then recieve snappy answers because tey are fed up with it.

and

> What can I do to defuse the situation apart from approaching the manager again?

Very little as you are not in position to tell the other team how to work. It's not your place to resolve it. What you can and should do is raise every instance of it with your manager and document you doing so.

What you can also do, although this depends on your relations with the other team, is to similarly start to document instances when work from someone else gets not delivered and then needs to be picked up by others. Ignore the illness, medication etc, it doesn't matter, what matters is that someone is not pulling their weight, and everyone else is expected to pick up the slack. Once you have the instances documented they can then raise it with their manager, or if ignored that mangers manager and demand action as this situation is unfair on everyone on that team.

But you sadly cannot do much more directly on that front, as you have a dependency on a team that is clearly under resourced, and from my point of view painfully mismanaged, so you have to document to build a solid case of why YOUR work is not being delivered, ideally turn that into some pro-active actions to avoid delays/misschedules.

On side note that picking of slack is a myth, because time doesn't come from nowhere so if a person A does extra 4 hours of work, that means they either did 4 hours of unpaid overtime, or did it instead of another task, unless otherwise they would just waste 4 hours doing nothing.  That's why this "shared tasklist" responsibility simply doesn't work with fixed deadlines and external dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

In a small family company, it's possible that nepotism would be the cause of a family member being allowed to sleep while their colleagues picked up the work.

But in a medium size company that is part of a large corporation, while it is possible that a family connection is enough to get this person a job that they are not obviously qualified for, your department head will know that they will be judged badly if they allow a worker to sleep on the job just because he is the future son in law of a team leader.

You say the team leaders and managers area aware of the situation, and probably have been since the beginning. In that case, there is nothing to be gained by telling them again, and the assumption that there is something else going on that you cannot be told about is probably safe. Be glad you work in a company and a society that values discretion, compassion and solidarity.

Has anyone befriended the new person? Perhaps you should. If you see them asleep on the job, reach out, show some compassion and ask them if they are ok, are they coping with the work, etc. Be genuine, not just fishing for gossip. If they are a halfway decent person they will know they are not doing their share and that it will have been noticed by their team mates. You may find that they confide in you why.

Answer (score 4):

The official, safe and recommended way, is to talk to your team lead and your manager *again*, explain that the problem still persists and ask for possible solutions.

One possible solution would be explaining to the team that this person will not work at full capacity due to medical reasons for exactly the "solidarity" reasons you mentioned. There is no need to go into *any* details. "Aus medizinischen Gründen" is a good and complete reason. As you said, it is very easy to band together and help someone who is sick or disabled, it is a lot worse for morale to pick up the pieces of a slacker just employed by virtue of nepotism.

Another (or additional) possible solution is to distribute workload differently. Plan for this person to not work to full capacity, so there is no overspill of unfinished tasks to the other member of the team. This is something a team lead can do independent of any issues and any medical "secrets". If the person only works half a day productively, then only *plan* for half a day for them. This way, nobody else has to cover for them.

Ask your teamlead and manager for a solution to the issue every time you have one of those talks where you bring up issues.

---

A little more personal risk, not official and only semi-recommended is doing something that might actually help, if teamlead and manager just don't want to bother, or are forbidden from doing it.

Talk to the person. Personally. In private. Explain to them exactly what you said here. That you and your team are very open to help someone, but the current perception is not that of a person in need of help, but of a person slacking off. And it would be a good idea *for them* to change that perception.

Make sure you tell them that you are not looking for medical details. Although it is not forbidden to ask for you as a private person with no postion of power in the company, it is still good to mention that explicitely before the talk.

This is a little more risky, because anything that happens is on you. You did that on your own. If they complain about you, whatever they bring up, it's your words against theirs.

I said "semi-recommended" because it can work... and it can backfire. And only you can judge that, based on you, your company and them. If it fits, it might be a solution, if it doesn't it might be 17 pointless HR meetings with one person accusing the other of saying or doing things that never happened.

Comment: Bringing the situation to the attention of the *Betriebsrat* could be worth a try. If someone at the team suffers from medical issues, they need appropriate accomodations and it is within the domain of the *Betriebsrat* to ensure they get these.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, especially since it sounds like you aren't their direct report or lead? If a team member is falling behind on work, your only responsibility should be to communicate that upwards IF it's impacting your deliverables directly.

Obviously, do this as objectively as you can. "I can't complete x because y has yet to be completed" or "I'm behind because I had to take on more work than usual this week".

It's also important to note that you should not be overworking yourself to cover someone else, otherwise it's harder for management to even realize there's a problem. It's expected that some team members will work slower than others, but if doesn't affect the overall team velocity, there's no reason for management to address that.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes in our lives we end up in a situation that is hard on us or others and is difficult to cope with. It might even seem unfair to us. I miss a bit more exact definition of "recently" in your post in order to define an exact time frame.

We were not all born in a perfect family and we have not all been raised in the perfect environment. Thus, through life we could start to cope with certain personal issues that are hard to resolve. If these issues are very serious it is almost impossible not to bring them in out quotidian life and even in the workplace.
There is not much written about the new colleague and his personal life, his problems, background, etc. You look at him as the guy who takes medication and has a higher-level protection. What if he is faced with certain personal issues, that you are not aware of, that are very hard on himself. He might not be able to do anything about it and might just has to cope with the consequences of something (he might have caused an accident when someone was seriously injured or even died - can you imagine that burden on yourself?). Maybe he has to carry the burden that hard that he has to help himself with medications. Very often anti-anxiety and anti-depression medications are influencing the way people function and can lead to sleepiness, etc.

If this is the case, it might help to get to know him a bit more. You can talk to him to get a better picture about the causes of his behaviour. If "recently" means a few months, can you give him some more time, like half a year or whole year, and judge the situation afterwards? Maybe this is what he needs now, and if he will recover, and is of any good, he will know how to return the favour later. If not, his underperformance will sooner or later become obvious throughout the whole company and for that you can consider all the other answers to your question.